# PHP storing variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code (shown below) and the variable $first_name=$_POST['first_name']; does not seem to work. I have username, password and title working. Is it something to do with the use of the underscore? I have checked that it matches with the database. When the user creates an account that line where the first_name is stored throws up an error and does not display the name entered in the database. Any ideas?

```
<?php
/* This code will make a connection with database */
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","","");

/* Now, we select the database */
mysql_select_db("");

/* Now we will store the values submitted by form in variable */
$username=$_POST['username'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
/* we are now encrypting password while using md5() function */
$password=md5($pass);
$confirm_password=$_POST['confirm_password'];

/* Now we will check if username is already in use or not */
$queryuser=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE username='$username' ");
$checkuser=mysql_num_rows($queryuser);
if($checkuser != 0)
{ echo "Sorry, ".$username." is already been taken."; }
else {

/* now we will check if password and confirm password matched */
if($pass != $confirm_password)
{ echo "Password and confirm password fields were not matched"; }
else {

/* Now we will write a query to insert user details into database */
$insert_user=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Customer (username, password, title, first_name) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$title', '$first_name')");

if($insert_user)
{ echo "Registration Succesfull"; }
else
{ echo "error in registration".mysql_error(); }

/* closing the if else statements */
}}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks!

HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="my.js">
        </script>
        <!-- User-generated css -->
        <style>
        </style>
        <!-- User-generated js -->
        <script>
            try {

    $(function() {

    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Your javascript has an error: " + error);
  }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="d" href="Login.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                    Back
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d"class="ui-btn-right">
                 Home  
                </a>
                <h3>
                    Registration
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <h4>
                    Enter your details below to register:
                </h4>

            <form method="post" action="Login.php">
            <table border="0">
            <tr><td>Title: </td><td><input type="text" name="title" /></td></tr>

            <tr><td>First Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="name" /></td></tr>

            <tr><td>Username: </td><td><input type="text" name="username" /></td></tr>

            <tr><td>Password: </td><td><input type="password" name="password" /></td></tr>

            <tr><td>Confirm Password: </td><td><input type="password" name="confirm_password" /></td></tr>

            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td></tr>

            </table>
            </form>
                <div data-role="content">
                <h4>
                 Please ensure your username and password are kept secure.
                </h4>

                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your form

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)`. Totally looks like a typo

Comment: Check the name of the field in your form, it's probably different than what you're referencing in `$_POST`. Also try `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's actually contained in the array.

Comment: May be some mistake in the name part for first name in your form. Can you post your form

Comment: While your code is not up to standard (you shouldn't be using mysql_*), it looks as if it should work.  Make sure that the `input` for your name has the attribute: `name="first_name"` in the HTML for your form.

Comment: @burmat, Thank you! Didn't have the first_name in the form. Thanks once again

Comment: @user2236990 No problem, glad you pin-pointed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your form attribute for input text for `first name` is `name` not `first_name` . So you should change

```
$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
```

to

```
$first_name=$_POST['name'];
```

or change your name attribute to `first_name`

Also do proper escaping for all fields before inserting

```
<?php
/* This code will make a connection with database */
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","","");

/* Now, we select the database */
mysql_select_db("");

/* Now we will store the values submitted by form in variable */
$username= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$pass= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$title= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$first_name= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

/* we are now encrypting password while using md5() function */
$password= md5($pass);
$confirm_password= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['confirm_password']);

/* Now we will check if username is already in use or not */
$queryuser=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE username='$username' ");
$checkuser=mysql_num_rows($queryuser);
if($checkuser != 0)
{ echo "Sorry, ".$username." is already been taken."; }
else {

/* now we will check if password and confirm password matched */
if($pass != $confirm_password)
{ echo "Password and confirm password fields were not matched"; }
else {

/* Now we will write a query to insert user details into database */
$insert_user=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Customer (username, password, title, first_name) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$title', '$first_name')");

if($insert_user)
{ echo "Registration Succesfull"; }
else
{ echo "error in registration".mysql_error(); }

/* closing the if else statements */
}}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

alter it to this:

`$first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);`

you are currently saving without any sanitization or escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$insert_user=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Customer (username, password, title, first_name) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$title', '$first_name')");
```

To this:

```
$insert_user=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Customer (username, password, title, first_name) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$title."', '".$first_name."')");
```

**UPDATE**

Please check that `<input type="text" name="first_name">` has `name="first_name"`

Comment: I think it's unnecessary, as double quotes treat dollar-prepended strings as variables

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: first_name in /web/stud/b12456/PHP2/Login.php on line 64 Registration Succesfull. This is the error i get. It is registering the title/username and password but not the first name

Comment: Are you sure that field name in DB is first_name? Could you post table create code?

Comment: @rinchik, its sorted. I didn't have first_name inside the form. Thanks!

Comment: Gotch ya! You have a problem in your HTML form

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like your form doesn't contain a `first_name` item, but `name`. Change it back to `first_name`